# Windowed functions cannot be used in the context of another windowed function or aggregate.SQL Server error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the row number for the rank. Below is the query,

```
 SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT rank() OVER (
                PARTITION BY o.panel_id
                ,o.combo_type_code ORDER BY row_number() OVER (
                        ORDER BY o.panel_id
                        )
                ) AS rank
            ,panel_code
        FROM tbk_offer_head o
            ,tbk_combo_type ct
            ,tbk_panel p
        WHERE o.panel_id = p.panel_id
            AND o.combo_type_code = ct.combo_type_code
            AND o.panel_id IN (
                SELECT p.panel_id
                FROM tbk_panel p
                WHERE p.campaign_id = 7392
                )
        ) A
    WHERE A.rank = 1
    ORDER BY panel_code
```

Getting the error, Windowed functions cannot be used in the context of another one. Please help how can i solve this problem.

Comment: Why do you need `row_number()`? You can just `order by o.panel_id` to get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what you are really trying to do.  But you should definitely learn to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

But there is no need to nest the functions.  Your logic should be equivalent to:

```
row_number() over (partition by o.panel_id, o.combo_type_code 
                   order by o.panel_id
                  ) as rank
```

Why does this use `row_number()` instead of `rank()`?  Your original `order by` used `row_number()` which never has duplicates.  Hence, if `rank()` could use it, the values would all be distinct, and the `rank()` would be equivalent to `row_number()` -- even when `panel_id` is duplicated.